# Set cookie on page load and hide div if cookie is present

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a site that shows a modal window when the page is loaded. I want this to only be shown to visitors the first time they come to the site however.

I have set JavaScript to add a cookie on page load but I want that cookie to be read (if present) and hide the modal (if cookie present).

I have the following Javascript (no jQuery):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') == -1) {
        var oneyear = 1000*60*60*24*365;
        var expires = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() +  oneyear);
        document.cookie = "visited=true;expires=" +  expires.toUTCString();
}

//Check if cookie is present and hide myModal DIV

if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('myModal').modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

My Html is:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="content">
            <p>Text to be shown here</p>
            <button id="closeBtn">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The cookie is being set on the page load, but it's not being read on second page load and hiding #myModal

** Update**

I have updated the above code, following the answers below but now I have got an error in the Console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

Comment: you are setting it as "visited=true;" and searching for 'visited=true='
Use correct string and it should work

Answer (score 3):

Modify this.You are checking string (`visited=true=`) wrong. Set it to `visited=true` or `visited=` is the best option as per me

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('myModal').modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and well spotted! I've done that but am now getting an error in the console: redirected.html:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: Where is the position of your javascript in your code?

Comment: In the head.You can view the location here: https://stormit.co.uk/ct-travel-test.html just click on the 'Redirect' link - which loads the modal window

Comment: Load it in footer section instead of head @RustyIngles

Comment: Thanks, I've done that. It's no longer showing the error in the console, but still not hiding the div

Comment: write `window.onload = function(){
 if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}
};`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176870/discussion-between-rustyingles-and-sudharshan-nair).

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the wrong string :

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true=') >= 0) {
```

should be

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=true') >= 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the .modal. that needs to be removed? I.e. change

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('myModal').modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

to:

```
if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: But string is `visited` instead of `visited=`